# How h2o return mcc value

Tags: machine-learning, h2o

I create random forrest model. mcc value are a list of two value. Why?

```
mRF=H2ORandomForestEstimator(nfolds=10,keep_cross_validation_models = True,seed=12345,model_id="RF0",ntrees=1000)
mRF.train(x=column_use, y=target, training_frame=train,validation_frame=valid)
print("MCC valid",mRF.model_performance(valid).mcc())
MCC valid [[0.35743618321170406, 0.21239407659849494]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't set the parameter threshold, it returns an array with one result for optimal threshold - [[optimal threshold, mcc]]. You can set the array of own thresholds - [threshold1, threshold2, ...] it will return [[threshold1, mcc1], [threshold2, mcc2], ... ].